# target to divs with data-toggle collapse

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

What I'm trying to achieve is toggle two divs with one link; so at the same time when this link is clicked toggle the `#virtual-gifts` div and `#external` div.

**The link I'm trying to use;**

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#virtual-gifts #external">test</a>
```

**The divs;**

```
<div id="external" class="collapse">
This is the external div
</div>

<div id="virtual-gifts" class="collapse">
This is the virtual-gifts div
</div>
```

Comment: You need to write JavaScript to do that. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use comma `,` to separate the id `#`like this:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#virtual-gifts,#external">test</a>
```

See more info about [Bootstrap data-attributes](https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#via-data-attributes-3)

Comment: thankyou, sorry I really should have tried that before posting this question, I really appreciate it though, thankyou will mark as answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you you should be able to target the 'a' with the below code.

```
$('a[data-toggle="collapse"]').on('click',function(){
   $('.collapse').toggle();
});
```